# soft - irc chat problem

Tags: windows-xp

On an irc chat,if i have ignore from another user, and i leave, when i enter again with my nick, i'm stucked, i can not type anything if the user is there... i must leave and enter another nick...
Same, if i am in the room and he enters... i get stucked, i have to leave and enter a different nick...

Same time, even that user has ignore from me also, he can type even if i enter the room...or if he enters and i am there... to me it apears (in the tab with private msg/ignore/invite) that he have not ignore from me (even if he didnt do anything to escape from ignore and i didnt unignore him)

Comment: More info please!  What IRC client are you using?  What do  you mean by "stucked"?  What IRC server are you using?